# CMS page with referer URL parameter

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I have a customised CMS page which includes a login form, I have code that lets me grab the referrer url parameter which works fine when testing in pure php.

However when putting this live I encounter a strange problem

If the URL to the cms page is \loginnew, the referral URL is \loginnew\referer\encodedurl which returns a not found page instead of the intended CMS page with paramaters

I'm not sure how to enable a CMS page to accept the refer parameter, but can capture the parameter when testing outside of Magento with code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344718/magento-customer-login-form-on-cms-page-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You may need a controller action that handles that submission and redirects to your \loginnew endpoint.

From the answer to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344718/magento-customer-login-form-on-cms-page-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1) you referenced did you use this code:

```
<?php $referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME); 
echo Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($referer);
?>
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/loginPost', array('referer' => $referer)); ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
```

May you post your template file and any other related code?